# modelname being tested is not defined error in Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-testing

I've an app called account_engine where in i have a model called CustomerAccount that needs to be tested.

**in models.py**

```
class CustomerAccount(models.Model):

    username = models.EmailField("Email Address")
    date_first_registered = models.DateTimeField()
    last_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    #password = models.TextField()
    password = EncryptedField(max_length=500)

    source = models.CharField(max_length = 10, null = True, blank = True)

    password_reset_token = models.CharField(max_length = 30, null = True, blank = True)


    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.id)

    def is_internal_email(self):
        # check if customer account is internal using email domain and set is_internal_email flag accordingly
        self.is_internal_email = False
        internal_emails = ['test.com', 'testing.com', 'testmail.com']
        customer_email = self.username.split('@')[1]
        for email in internal_emails:
            if email == customer_email:
                self.is_internal_email = True
        return self.is_internal_email
```

**in my tests.p**

```
import datetime
from django.test import TestCase
from account_engine import models


class CustomerAccountTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        CustomerAccount.objects.create(
            username = 'test@test.com',
            date_first_registered = '2018-05-15 12:32:35.817018',
            password = 'Test@12345'
        )

    def test_get_customeraccount(self):

        first_customer = CustomerAccount.objects.first()
        self.assertEqual(first_customer.username, 'test@test.com')
```

on running python manage.py test, i get the following error

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_get_customeraccount (account_engine.tests.tests_models.CustomerAccountTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\xxxxxxx\account_engine\tests\tests_models.py", line 9, in setUp
    CustomerAccount.objects.create(
NameError: name 'CustomerAccount' is not defined

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I've just started to learn testing in django, so this might be a very simple mistake. yet I'm not able to figure it out. 
Also, how can i test my methods defined in the model ?
Also, what all should one test in the model ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has actually nothing to do with Django itself, it's basic Python stuff. Python's `import` mechanism has nothing to do with C or PHP includes, as you would know if you had done [the official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#modules):

> `>>> import fibo`
>
> This does not enter the names of the functions defined in fibo
>   directly in the current symbol table; it only enters the module name
>   fibo there. Using the module name you can access the functions:
>
> `>>> fibo.fib(1000)`

Trying to use Django without learning Python first will be an exercise in pain and frustration, so really, take a day to do the full official tutorial and browse the doc to get a sense of what is there and where to find it, it'll really save you a lot of time.

> Also, how can i test my methods defined in the model ?

Err... by calling them and checking the result ?

> Also, what all should one test in the model ?

Anything that's not standard (your own added methods, and the one you override). You can safely assume that Django works as expected - not that it's totally bug free (which code is ?), but it's really battlefield-tested code for most parts so chances you find a bug in basic features are more than slim.

Comment: thank you. I realized my mistake. changing import statement from `from account_engine import models` to `from account_engine.models import CustomeAccount` resolved it